# Quill remove colour from pasted text

Tags: reactjs, quill

I am using React Quill and want to remove colour from pasted text, so that quill should show text in black colour only. I have tried Clipboard module but not able to understand how to remove colour. Has anyone achieved this?

Thanks,
MSK

Answer (score 2):

Quill has config option with a list of allowed [formats](https://quilljs.com/docs/configuration/#formats).

Demo that whitelist only link and size:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xBWved

```
var quill = new Quill('#editor-container', {
  modules: {
    toolbar: [
      [{ header: [1, 2, false] }],
      ['bold', 'italic', 'underline'],
      ['image', 'code-block']
    ]
  },
  formats: ['link', 'size'],
  placeholder: 'Compose an epic...',
  theme: 'snow'  // or 'bubble'
});
```

List of all supported formats:
https://quilljs.com/docs/formats/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can register the color module and whitelist:

```
const ColorAttributor = Quill.import("attributors/style/color");
ColorAttributor.whitelist = [];
Quill.register(ColorAttributor);
```